# Looking at the source of a dynamic dropdown applet or database?

Tags: javascript, html, database

So I'm looking at http://ohiostate.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/BNCBHomePage?storeId=33552&catalogId=10001 and was wondering if there was a way I could get all of the possible classes/options for the courses in a semester. There's a class locator on the top left of the page, and it has a dynamic drop down menu. Is there any way for me to view the source of the database?

Comment: for what . to build your own website .:)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible.

The drop down menu is generated dynamically on the server side, and then the results are presented in your browser.

Viewing the source of the database is also out of the question - it is secure.

I'd suggest you check with your college/university and ask them if they have a list of all the courses in a semester available as a text file/CSV, etc.

Good Luck.